# SlowSort Implementation in C#

Tags: c#, performance, sorting

Only thing I found was the wikipedia entry.
I tried to render it in C#.

```
public void slowersort(List<string>Value, int start, int ende)
{
    start = 0;
    ende = Value.Count-1;
    if i < j:
    {
       int middle = (start+ende)/2;
        slowersort(Value, start, ende)
        slowersort(Value, middle + 1, ende)
        if (Value[middle].CompareTo(Value[j]) == 1)
         for (int i = 0; i > ende-middle, i++)
             Value[k], Value[k + 1] = Value[k + 1], Value[k]
        slowersort(Value, start, ende - 1)
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work, my program doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What do you mean by _Doesnt seem to work_ exactly? Do you get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific? Please read [FAQ] and [ask] as a start..

Comment: And please.. do _not_ kiss anyone's feet unless you are not a fetish.

Comment: Also you code won't _even_ compile. It would be better to create a [MCVE] at least..

Comment: If "doesn't work" == "worthless sorting algorithm", that is by-design. If you're the type that enjoys copying and pasting code without understanding it, [this is your gold mine](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Data-Structures-Algorithms-d68f1418/sourcecode?fileId=132787&pathId=2010985077).

Comment: @SonerGönül thanks for the starting guide, gonna look into it and post it more specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time check your code.  Here is Wiki page : http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SlowSort

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> input = new List<string>() { "z", "y", "x", "w", "v", "u", "t", "s" };
            Test test = new Test();
            test.slowersort(input, 0, input.Count - 1);

        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void slowersort(List<string>Value, int start, int ende)
        {
            if (start < ende)
            {
                int middle = (start+ende)/2;
                slowersort(Value, start, middle);
                slowersort(Value, middle + 1, ende);
                if (Value[middle].CompareTo(Value[ende]) == 1)
                {
                    string temp = Value[middle];
                    Value[middle] = Value[ende];
                    Value[ende] = temp;
                }
                slowersort(Value, start, ende - 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```